# C Segmentation fault in struct. Code translated from Matlab->C with Matlab Coder

Tags: c++, c, matlab, struct

I am translating some Matlab functions to C with Matlab Coder. Everything works to the point, where i want to return an array(transposed vector) from my function.

In Matlab I have a function:

```
function returnedArray = myFun(input arguments)
<function code>
```

This call to the function in C gets translatet to:

```
void myFun(input arguments, emxArray_realT *returnedArray)
<function code>
```

emxArray_real_T is a struct, that was generated by Matlab Coder:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
    real_T *data;
    int32_T *size;
    int32_T allocatedSize;
    int32_T numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

And real_T, int32_T... are created generic type definitions:

```
typedef double real_T;
```

I call this myFun from main:

```
struct emxArray_real_T *result = malloc(sizeof(struct emxArray_real_T));

myFun(input arguments, result);
```

When i run this, i get an error saying: Segmentation fault. 
gdb gave me this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault at:
99643: i0=retArray->size[0];

p retArray
$1 = (emxArray_real_T *) 0xc1d010

p retArray.size
$2 = (int32_T *) 0x0

p retArray.size[0]
Cannot access memora ar adress 0x0
```

Am i doing something wrong in my main function? I hope so, because translated code from Matlab in C is a mess, or maybe just for me as a novice.
The code works fine, if I translate and compile it in C without the return value.

Comment: This looks like the `retArray` is not initialized properly, since it's `size` member points to 0 instead of an allocated `int32_T`. It would help, if you could provide us with your whole code. -- Edit: not your own code, but the generated :p

Comment: This could be tricky, because there is more than 100000 lines in this function. But you assume there could be a problem in code translated with Matlab Coder?

Comment: I just realized I am looking right at the error.

Comment: This up there in comment is basically it. There are just a few lines more to read and store user input from command line to variables, that are passed in to myFun.

Comment: Did you try to generate code from matlab-code actually calling the function? that would presumably show you how to properly initialize the array.

Comment: Can you show us your function in MATLAB?

Comment: I believe you are missing some `malloc` calls. Since there are 2 pointers in struct, you will have to point them to an allocated memory before assigning any data to them

Comment: @sebastian: i haven't yet, but i will if i can't fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call this from main:

```
struct emxArray_real_T *result = malloc(sizeof(struct emxArray_real_T));

// result->size == 0;
// You would need to initialize this too.
// Somewhere in myFun it is accessed like this:
//   *retArray->size = x;
// or
//   x = *retArray->size;
// which causes the fault.

myFun(input arguments, result);
```

Since I don't know anything about Matlab, I can't tell you if this is something you have to do, or if this should be done by the generated code somewhere.

You can try to fix it like this:

```
result->size = malloc(sizeof(int32_T));
```

Comment: do not cast the result of `malloc`. This will hide compiler errors.

Comment: This works now, great. I put result->size=malloc(sizeof(int32_T)) in my main function, before calling myFun. @hhachem pointed out that this hides compiler errors, so is this something a shoul be careful about or shoul i do this some other way? Again thanks for you answer Qntm.

Comment: There are multiple reasons not to cast `malloc`'s return value. 1) It is a `void*` which gets implicitly casted to any other pointer type. Hence the additional cast is unnecessary verbose and makes reading harder. 2) The cast hides an compiler error if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`. There are a bunch of good articles about this problem [here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=malloc+cast).

Comment: Generally you should of course check `malloc`'s return value against `0`, since this is the return value indicating allocation errors.